# How to implement multi-window feature?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, crm

We're developing a web application using Asp.NET MVC with a `multi-window feature` (ex. when you select a record, a new browser window pops up with the selected record's details in it). I've stumbled accross ***Microsoft's CRM*** and it behaves exactly what my superior wanted. It opens a new browser window when you select and view a certain record on their list.

My question is, is that really a new browser window? When I look it up in the task manager, the windows I opened doesn't appear on the *Process Tab* except for the main browser window. And if it is a new browser window, is it much better than using a jQuery modal window?

**NOTE:** I'm using Internet Explorer 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 1st question is quit general.
I would guess that you know how to open a new window using javascript or jquery dialog so i don't understand what elese do you need.

you 2nd question is what works better and this is really a UX related question that i have asked before and found this: 
[Why Modal Windows Have Killed Popup Windows](http://uxmovement.com/forms/why-modal-windows-have-killed-popup-windows/)

Comment: As for question #1, I'm just puzzled why Microsoft still used popup windows on their CRM although it's heavier than modals because it loads css and scripts everytime you open one. Anyway, thanks for the link! And I agree that modals are much better.